# Capture and stop dragging on a touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, touch

I am making a site which I want to capture when people scroll.

For mousewheel I have done the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document)
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        if(animating == 1) {return;}
        if(delta > 0) {
            var newpage = (page - 1);
            if(newpage < 0) newpage = 0;
            slidepage(newpage, scrolllen);
        } else {
            var newpage = (page + 1);
            if(newpage > 6) newpage = 6;
            slidepage(newpage, scrolllen);
        }
    });
});
```

I am also capturing space bar and arrow keys, all of these moving a div based on what is pressed to give the illusion of sliding around a page(when it's actually the page that slides).  These all work perfectly.  However, on an ipad or similar, users can scroll around the website as they please which is something which detracts from the experience.  How might I capture this input simply?

Comment: have you tried using the touchmove events?

Comment: No, I haven't.  Just tried, and it looks hopeful.  Can you write it as answer so I can send you a tick, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the touchmove events